# How to merge two test cases with Groovy Spock where a void type of method once succeeds and once throws exception

Tags: java, validation, filter, groovy, spock

I have the following 2 test cases for the same method.

The first calls a service where there is no result (because the service method is a `void`).

The second calls the same service but then it results with an exception.

How can I merge these two test cases into one by using the @Unroll and `where` parts?

Test 1:

```
def "test is valid by case - valid"() {
    given: "data to validate"
    Data data = Mock()
    
    when: "trying to check if valid"
    def result = validationService.isValidByCriteria(data)

    then: "no exception is thrown"
    noExceptionThrown()
    and: "validation is called without exception"
    1 * validationLogic.validate(data)
    and: "no exception therefore true returns"
    result
}
```

Test 2:

```
def "test is valid by case - invalid"() {
    given: "data to validate"
    Data data = Mock()
    
    when: "trying to check if valid"
    def result = validationService.isValidByCriteria(data)

    then: "no exception is thrown"
    noExceptionThrown()
    and: "validation is called with exception"
    1 * validationLogic.validate(data) >> {throw new Exception()}
    and: "exception therefore false returns"
    !result
}
```

Comment: An example that can be reproduced without requiring your hidden classes and services would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you should bake those two tests into a single one, because they represent different feature behaviours. I understand your motivation to reduce duplicate code, though.

I guess your situation is roughly as follows:

```java
class ValidationService {
  ValidationLogic validationLogic

  boolean isValidByCriteria(Data data) {
    try {
      validationLogic.validate(data)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      println "Validation error: $e.message"
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

```java
class ValidationLogic {
  void validate(Data data) {
    if (data.name.contains('x'))
      throw new Exception('invalid data')
  }
}
```

```java
class Data {
  String name
}
```

Then your original test runs as given. One way to unify those two methods looks like this:

```java
class ValidationServiceTest extends Specification {
  def validationLogic = Mock(ValidationLogic)
  def validationService = new ValidationService(validationLogic: validationLogic)

  @Unroll('#resultType result')
  def 'validation service returns normally'() {
    given: 'data to validate'
    Data data = Mock()

    when: 'trying to check if valid'
    def result = validationService.isValidByCriteria(data)

    then: 'service does not throw any exceptions'
    noExceptionThrown()
    and: 'validation is called'
    1 * validationLogic.validate(data) >> { if (!expectedResult) throw new Exception('oops') }
    and: 'result is as expected'
    result == expectedResult

    where:
    resultType | expectedResult
    'valid'    | true
    'invalid'  | false
  }
}
```

In IntelliJ IDEA the unrolled feature is represented like this:

[image: IDEA test results]

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eNqFVE2P0zAQvedXDAuSEw6RdpFYFGlXiI8bXGjZKzLONLXq2MF200bb_nf8lWybFnFL5-O9N2_G7Sjb0AahxtIwvW1_tdRY1KWxLqF61CuhduWf-_vbd-_v7j5kGW87pS2YTrFNKahsykWHjK84o5YreSX_U2olRJYxQY2BJyp4HUoXqHvOcInGAu4tytrAGRY8Z-CEraCfer6phjN4gO8OPX86DxcX1YnB1UvcXTLnM9xqTlRkDvJj1J-T1xrNVtjl0CHETzJSkpdGMIlUo91qaUAq3VIhBpIXYSCAhvcoKyCugYJVIyuSkP3ioyGVxgwqAHbr0GT1wGXj29ga2QZ4Gjg2ezFRm-u-MKLkJpjwafisudsyp7knSgQ2Eoz6a4VevHVxrXZA5eC2xLDzeCaySfV1jCx9kcyLEKeyrs484QaY8wCTylt4O7e6HE2IiuDxEZ79bPkr3LubsFj_CGMVSY5f6ESeE6U6Qwo4ntAnGxw1NTCCRP7RoQc4B5-M1lidFIaNH-a1Ph9nJP7zAFZvMUa5HOMHWFFhfPiYHf_5BMJdzK55bpDX9lspgdTbOV_jdDTjjbkzSV_wH6tDUTTOPTu2hnzyFbCYQDrNpRUSbl50AmqtdAVvsGzRGPc3cpOK4-1Ps4_4KZyMuupInN2T9orX09O4HNDfhv9dStpiyZS0lEuTkz0piqTi6qWk3QSs8H5PZAQSD7-w2j8yD-2yfwGj_7Mk).

Comment: Ahh. I forgot to think about the 'if' condition. Thanks for the example!